# Does spacy's Lemmatizer depend on the dependency parser?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am running a spacy pipeline over my text and find that the lemmatizer returns different results depending on if I have the parser running or not. What I am trying to understand is if the lemmatizer utilizes only the POS element of the parser or if it also uses the dependency parsing aspect.

The long story is that I have an inhouse built NLP pipeline that I must migrate to for work and I need to specify the pipeline more directly. My goal is to, as near as possible, replicate the spacy results (for continuity purposes). This should be feasible with my framework I just need to understand how the dependencies flow in the spacy pipeline which is unclear to me from the docs.